# Clean install of Ubuntu in a laptop running Windows 10

Tags: system-installation

I have 3 drives(C,D,E) on my laptop and windows 10 is installed at C. Now if i install Ubuntu 14 and choose the option "Replace Windows with Ubuntu", will it delete all current data from my D and E drive?

Comment: I'm not sure. I can't predict the behavior of those replace buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will. The installer will assume it can format ALL drives if ONLY Ubuntu is to be installed.

If you want to keep any of the partitions use "something else" and do NOT format the partitions you want to keep. The Ubuntu partitioner will tell you what partition holds the OS by the way.

**If you are unsure:** *check the size of the partitions in Windows first before trying!*

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will. In fact, it will delete all the windows partitions C, D and E. First, you should create different partitions for ubuntu and create a backup for windows so that in case of any mistake, you will not use your data. Then, you should go for something else option. For step by step method, a good tutorial:

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html

It will Dual boot windows and ubuntu. It means you can use both windows and ubuntu.

If you want to install only ubuntu,then go for the replace windows with ubuntu options. I think you are a newbie. So, you should go for dual boot.